# Is there a way to calculate average with only values in the columns greater than 0 in dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Is there a way to calculate average with only values in the columns greater than 0 in dataframe?
I have a dataset with the structure below.

```
Week    |Mon    |Tues   |Weds      |Thurs  |Fri    |Sat     |Sun    |average
:-------:-------:-------:----------:-------:-------:--------:-------:-----------
1       |5915   |2997   |8499      |1248   |3089   |1343    |0      |3298.71
2       |0      |0      |3588      |5693   |1297   |288     |2453   |1902.71
```

Using mean will get all the values in the stated columns which gives Total/7.
`df['average'] = df[['Mon', 'Tues','Weds','Thurs','Fri','Sat','Sun']].mean(axis=1)`

Is there a way to get results in with the following:

```
Week    |Mon    |Tues   |Weds      |Thurs  |Fri    |Sat     |Sun    |average (desired output)
:-------:-------:-------:----------:-------:-------:--------:-------:--------------------------------
1       |5915   |2997   |8499      |1248   |3089   |1343    |0      |(5915+2997+8499+1248+3089+1343)/6
2       |0      |0      |3588      |5693   |1297   |288     |2453   |(3588+5693+1297+288+2453)/5
```

Answer (score 2):

Just add another layer of boolean indexing to make it only positive numbers:

```
df[df[['Mon', 'Tues','Weds','Thurs','Fri','Sat','Sun']]>0].mean(axis=1)
```